# Getting HTML form input with C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms

I am having a problem getting HTML input values using C# for a Login page. I have had luck using just a regular ASP element, but not so much with pure HTML.

I am trying to have the C# grab the username input and password from the html form to then send as a string to a MySQL db proc. If the username/password combination does not exist, I am trying to redirect back to the Login.aspx page and if it does "google.com". The username and password are also saved in a session.

My HTML looks like the following:

```
<form action="Login.aspx.cs" runat="server" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="un" pattern="a[0-9]{6}" required="required" placeholder="a000000"/><br />
            <input type="password" name="pw"  required="required" /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="text" runat="server" OnClick="Login1_Authenticate" />
</form>
```

And my C# looks like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int status;
    int role;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {

        //// create an open connection
        SqlConnection conn =
            new SqlConnection("Data Source=MachineName;"
            + "Initial Catalog=DBName;"
            + "User ID=Usr ;Password=Password");

        conn.Open();

        string userName = Page.Request.Form["un"].ToString();
        string pw = Page.Request.Form["pw"].ToString();
        //userName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());


        //// create a SqlCommand object for this connection
        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.SP_CA_CHECK_USER @USER_ID = '" + userName + "', @PASSWORD = '" + pw + "'";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //// execute the command that returns a SqlDataReader
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        //// display the results
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            status = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }

        //// close first reader
            reader.Close();


            if (status == 0)
            {
                //login
                Session["userID"] = userName;
                command.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.SP_CA_RETURN_USER_ROLE @USER_ID = '" + userName + "'";
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    role = reader.GetInt32(0);
                }

                Session["roleID"] = role;

                if (Session["userID"] != null)
                {
                    string userID = (string)(Session["userID"]);
                    // string roleID = (string)(Session["roleID"]);
                }
                Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com");
            }
            else
            {
                //wrong username/password
                Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com");
            }



            // close the connection
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Add an `id` attribute to your input fields.  `id="un"` and `id="pw"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do several things:

1. Change the form action to `Login.aspx`, not to the code behind file (.cs)
2. Remove the `runat="server"` from the form. It doesn't harm, but it would make sense only if your `<form>` tag had to be rendered on server side, and that's not the case: it's pure HTML. It would make sense if, for example, some of the `<form>` attributes depended on server code.
3. Use a simple `<input type="submit" value="Login button caption">` button to POST the form.
4. Implement the code in the `Page_Load` event, but only if `IsPostback` is true (that means that the page is being rendered in response to a POST request).

Explanation: if you post a form in the standard way to the `.aspx` file, its code behind will run. If the login form is requested for the first time, for example by typing its URL in the browser, the request is a GET and the server must send the empty form to the browser. But, if the user clicks the submit button, it is a POST request, and the code behind must try to login the user. To differentiate between GET and POST you can use the `IsPostback` property: if it's true, it's a POST. If not, it's a get. You can do that directly in the `Page_Load` event.

In the case where the user has entered the wrong username and password, you must return the original form to get the user a new chance to login. As you're using standard HTML controls, there is no `ViewState`. That means that the posted `un` value (user name), will be lost, unless you set it back on the server before sending the form to the user. You can use the `<% = %>` syntax to set the `input value` attribute, so that the entered user name is returned to the browser.

Take into account that mixing up pure HTML and server controls can get tricky. If you take a path, you'd better follow it, and don't mix things up, unless you know very well what you're doing. So, in my explanation I'm only using pure standard HTML / HTTP approach.